# 201901 - relativedelta(weeks=1) gets 201900

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm sorry if there was a topic like this one, but I didn't know how to formulate a question to find something similar. As I said it gets 201900, while I need 201852. Any advice? Thanks!

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

year = str(current_date.isocalendar()[0])
wk = str(current_date.isocalendar()[1])
weektoday = year+'0'+wk

neededwk = datetime.datetime.strptime(weektoday, '%Y%w%W')

if datetime.date.today().isoweekday() == 1:
    neededwk = neededwk - relativedelta(weeks=2)
else:
    neededwk = neededwk - relativedelta(weeks=1)

neededwk = neededwk.strftime('%Y%W')
```

For details: [relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html)

Comment: What is `relativedelta()`?

Comment: is that some kind of trolling thing when a new guy asks?

Comment: The result of your code is relevant to `current_date`, so how do you set `current_date`?

Comment: No you're not being "trolled". See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @keineahnung2345 its current_date = datetime.date.today()

Comment: @martineau https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html ; OP: dateutil is a non-standard package, so you should mention it where it comes from (I've now provided an edit to your question).

Comment: @9769953 thanks, I'll do better next time!